# Chi Square embedded in an ANOVA model?

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, clinical-trials

I have treatment->outcomes count data, which is obviously modeled by a chi squared, but there are several separate ones, let's say 3. I could run 3 separate chi squares, but I want to ask what would naturally be an ANOVA-like question about which is these is better, distributing the error across all 3, as an ANOVA would do. But they aren't continuous data (and it doesn't make sense to just turn the counts into ratios because there's really just one ratio that's slowly changing as you get more counts, not a sample from a space of real-valued data!).

The model I'm looking for is a little like the layer concept in SPSS crosstab (aka. control layer), but I think of that as another dimension/category. I suppose that I could model the separate treatments as a confounding categorical  factor.

Is there a single simple model that captures this sort of configuration?

(I'm thinking that there must be because it's more-or-less what happens in any clinical trial that has more than one treatment, like an umbrella trial. So maybe, I'm not realizing, what I want to do is to look at the model for an umbrella trial....)

(ps. I have examined the several search hits that come up with this entry, most are not answered, and the ones that are answered are answering simpler questions, like the difference between a chisq and an anova.)

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. If I understood correctly you have two categorical variables: treatment and outcome. Say, you have treatment X, Y and Z; and you have outcomes A, B and C. I have doubts if I understood your question: as you asking if treatment X has the same probability distribution of outcomes as treatment Y or treatment Z?

Comment: E.g., 3 txs, binary outcomes, and a flow of light bulbs. I want to find the best tx (Bayesianly, so I stop when I have found it). For each bulb, I apply a random tx and then hit the bulb with a hammer. My measure is not continuous, like length of life, which would just be an ANOVA model. This is more like a Chi squared, or a logit embedded into an ANOVA. Bayes aside, I could simply power the experiment and do exactly that. ... Hmmm. I may have just talked myself into a logit-based ANOVA, which I could conduct repeatedly (with appropriate FDR correction)....?

Comment: So, you have 2 outcomes (bulb breaks: yes or no) and 3 treatments (X, Y or Z) that may be applied to the bulb? Something like:    $$\begin{array}{c|cc} treat \backslash outcome & y & n \\ \hline X & 99 & 101 \\ Y & 143 & 265 \\ Z & 87 & 64 \end{array}$$ If this is the case, then a chi-square test for independence is the way to go; however, I feel you may have another variable and you might want to do a logistic regression.